# При записи dataframe в таблицу SQLite возвращает ошибку sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, requests

1. Получаю JSON из API:

```
response = requests.get(url, auth=(api_key, password)).json()
```

Ответ получаю, данные верные.

2. После кладу данные из ответа в dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(response)
```

На этом шаге тоже всё в порядке, фрейм формируется

3. Создаю подключение к базе SQLite

```
con = sqlite3.connect('.../new_db', timeout=10)
cur = con.cursor()
```

4. И пробую записать в базу полученный фрейм

```
df.to_sql(con=con, name='test_table', index=False, if_exists='replace')
```

В итоге получаю ошибку

> sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.

Полученный JSON никак не обрабатываю, таблица в базе создаётся с правильными типами.
Возможно необходима какая-то обработка, приведение типов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

у вас в data frame затесалось поле типа dict (словарь), содержащее не просто строку, а пары ключ-значение, и которое не может непосредственно загрузиться в SQLite

Comment: Спасибо, суть проблемы понял. Может быть знаете, есть ли возможность принудительно сказать, что любое такое поле считать string?

Comment: У вас json. формат, который словарь ключ-значение, как вы хотите превратить это в строку?

Comment: Хотел прямо JSONом в некоторые поля класть.

Решил доставать нужные вложенные в словарь данные так
`df["name"].map(
        lambda x: x.get("sub_name", np.nan) if isinstance(x, dict) else np.nan)`

Спасибо.

Comment: Тогда вам надо преобразовать его (сконвертировать) в строку, и складывать строку (и если вы получили ответ на вопрос - отметье его верным)